# Parsing JSON with dynamic Object Names

Tags: java, json, parsing, jackson

I am trying to parse some data from Fantasy Football API to do some analysis.

It returns an object called "elements" I am not too sure how to setup my Objects and Jackson annotations so the mapper picks it up correctly. Do I require an object for each of the different child objects even though it is just their name is different?

JSON example:

```
   {
  "elements": {
    "1": {
      "explain": [
        [
          [
            {
              "name": "Minutes played",
              "points": 2,
              "value": 90,
              "stat": "minutes"
            },
            {
              "name": "Goals conceded",
              "points": -1,
              "value": 2,
              "stat": "goals_conceded"
            },
            {
              "name": "Saves",
              "points": 2,
              "value": 6,
              "stat": "saves"
            }
          ],
          1
        ]
      ],
      "stats": {
        "minutes": 90,
        "goals_scored": 0,
        "assists": 0,
        "clean_sheets": 0,
        "goals_conceded": 2,
        "own_goals": 0,
        "penalties_saved": 0,
        "penalties_missed": 0,
        "yellow_cards": 0,
        "red_cards": 0,
        "saves": 6,
        "bonus": 0,
        "bps": 24,
        "influence": 47,
        "creativity": 0,
        "threat": 0,
        "ict_index": 4.7,
        "total_points": 3,
        "in_dreamteam": false
      }
    },
    "2": {
      "explain": [
        [
          [
            {
              "name": "Minutes played",
              "points": 0,
              "value": 0,
              "stat": "minutes"
            }
          ],
          1
        ]
      ],
      "stats": {
        "minutes": 0,
        "goals_scored": 0,
        "assists": 0,
        "clean_sheets": 0,
        "goals_conceded": 0,
        "own_goals": 0,
        "penalties_saved": 0,
        "penalties_missed": 0,
        "yellow_cards": 0,
        "red_cards": 0,
        "saves": 0,
        "bonus": 0,
        "bps": 0,
        "influence": 0,
        "creativity": 0,
        "threat": 0,
        "ict_index": 0,
        "total_points": 0,
        "in_dreamteam": false
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: That JSON seems pretty convoluted. Broad observation: the objects with property `name`, `points`, etc. can be definitely de-serialized into a single POJO type. Same with the `stats` objects. The worst part comes now: the `explain` objects seem to be an array of an array of an array (whew) of those easily de-serializable POJOs first mentioned. Finally the `elements` root object can be de-serialized as a map of string-representing-integers, with an object composed of an `explain` and a `stats` objects. Bottomline, you're not going to have your work cut out easily...

Comment: Fine-tune: just noticed the intermediary-level array for `explain` also has a single dangling integer there, so you're going to have to be "creative" with that, and likely de-serialize the intermediate array as a `List<Object>` or such like. What a mess...